# What this shape name? (concave laterally and straight medially, cross section shape of crayfish rostrum)

Tags: zoology, morphology

What is a shape name for upper surface (colored black) of the cross-sectional shape in the attached image? It is a cross-section through a crayfish rostrum. It is horizontal and linear medially, but concave laterally. By shape name, I'm thinking of words along the lines of emarginate, cuspidate, etc:
[image]

Comment: In what way is this a _biology_ question?

Comment: This is a shape I see in a crayfish rostrum.  It would be nice to describe it succinctly if possible.

Comment: Then please edit the question and include this information in it, possibly with an image.

Comment: @crayman9 it would help if you could label the parts of the image or even use a drawing tool to make a better drawing. For instance are the 2 left and 2 right asterisks parts of the body or the claws? Is the line the ventrum of the animal? Which part of the animal was the section through.

Comment: Ok, I added a drawing.  I didn't realize it was as simple as drag and drop.

Comment: Laggingly/tardily concave is the best I could think of. Imagine it takes time to become concave.